# Advice on storing (and re-loading) 10,000+ user-defined objects in Python on disk

Tags: python, bigdata, hdf5, pickle

I am currently using Python's cPickle module to perform the following tasks:

```
1) Create +10,000 instances of a user-defined class.
2) Put all instances in a dictionary.
3) cPickle (using "dump(...)") this dictionary.
```

The pickled file takes up ~100 mb.

When I call the code again it then uses "load(...)" to load in the instances again.

The above approach works fine.

**My question is**: is this the best way of doing this? That is, the problem seems like it should be common so people must have come up with some very efficient way of doing this and I just want to make sure I am not missing this.

E.g., I have heard of HDF5, but I believe this is not useful for instances of user-defined functions as far as I can tell from looking it up?

Comment: You say "the above approach works fine."  So what's the problem?

Comment: "big data" likes to scan and filter smaller records so that you don't have to work with large datasets all the time. Instead of putting 10000 objects into a dict, you could write one per line to the file. Another option is to define a json representation of the class and use something like Hadoop or Couch to do the heavy lifting.